# How to make something look like it is flickering

Tags: python, pygame

I have a scrolling background game, where you can control a character as they move around the screen (like Mario). How do I make it so that if the character hits something on the ground, such as a spike, it starts flickering?

Comment: loop over render and not render the flickering sprite, so it will switch between visible and invisible.

Comment: @okie what do you mean render? I am using blit right now, is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

Do stuffs like:

```
#in chr initial
self.deathloop = 0
```

```
#in loop (if you have a update function specific for chr)


if self.death == True:
 if self.deathloop < 30:
  blit
 elif self.deathloop < 60:
  pass
 else:
  deathloop = 0
 deathloop +=1
```

Or anyway that `blit` chr for certain time and then stop `blit` it for same amount of time, thus it will visible when it was `blit` and invisible when it's not `blit`.

Comment: I tried this in my code, but it said blit was not defined. Should I put another variable after blit?

Comment: blit was mean for adding your codes that draw character.